# For each Monday in the calendar insert the following in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, time

I have a table like this one in the database:

```
Create table Reservation (
  DayOfTheWeek varchar(50) ,
  DesiredTime Time,
  DateReservation Date,
  EmployeeNumber int reference Employees(EmployeeNumber),
  CONSTRAINT pk_StandingReservation PRIMARY KEY (DayOfTheWeek,DesiredTime)
)
```

So what I want to do is Insert for example:

`Date reservation`, `DesiredTime`, `EmployeeNumber` and `DayOftheWeek` for each Monday in the calendar in a period of 4 months!

How do you do it in SQL SERVER ?

Comment: I would probably use `DATEADD()` and a tally table.  However, I think you're going to run into problems with a primary key like the one you have.  You can only have one reservation at 1:00 PM on a Wednesday.  You can't have one at 1:00 PM on Wednesday, December 10, 2014, as well as one at 1:00 PM on Wednesday, December 17, 2014.  It doesn't matter that the dates are different or the employee might be different.  There's only one 1:00 PM slot on a Wednesday for any employee on any date.

Comment: So what's your qestion exactly? How to generate a list of all Mondays for next 4 months?